# MVC $.ajax call never executes controller action on Edit but works on Add

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC5 and calling $.ajax to populate my "Subdivision" dropdown based on the Customer selection (certain subdivisions belong to certain customers). When I go to my Add view, the following JavaScript works fine. However, when I go to the Edit view and I run the exact same script, it does not work.

I put a breakpoint in the getSubdivisions() controller method and it works fine on the Add page. However, the $.ajax call never hits the controller action when I'm on the Edit page. The $.ajax call just fails. What is the problem?

I have the following line at the end of both the Add and Edit views:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/schedule")
```

The ~/bundles/schedule file is defined in BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/schedule").Include("~/Scripts/mainsys/schedule.js"));
```

Here is my JavaScript...

```
try {
    $('#CustomerID').change(function () {
        getSubdivisions();
    });

    getSubdivisions();
}
catch (ex) {
    alert(ex.message);
}

function getSubdivisions() {
    custId = $('#CustomerID').val();

    // remove all of the current options from the list
    $('#SubdivisionID').empty();

    // send request for list of subdivisions
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: './getSubdivisions',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{ customerId: ' + custId.toString() + ' }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: true
    });

    // received list of models...
    jqxhr.done(function (data) {
        if (data == null) return;

        try {
            var ddl = $('#SubdivisionID');

            // add each item to DDL
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                ddl.append($('<option></option>', { value: data[index].SubdivisionID }).html(data[index].SubdivisionName))
            });
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert("Done, but with errors!\n" + ex.message);
        }
    });

    // failed to retrieve data
    jqxhr.error(function (result, errorText, thrownError) {
        alert("Error! Failed to retrieve models! " + errorText + "\n" + thrownError);
    });
}
```

Here is my controller method...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string getSubdivisions(int customerId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (customerId <= 0) return null;

            List<s84_Subdivision_Short> lst = s84_Subdivision.listItemsShort(customerId);
            string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
            return s;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

The jqxhr.error...

```
errorText is "parsererror" and thrownError is "Invalid character."
```

UPDATE: In Firefox the error shows up as "JSON.parse: unexpected character"

Comment: WOW! This seems stupid. I changed the $.ajax call so that it does not use a relative path... Everything works now. If anyone wants to explain why this works (below) versus what I originally used, I'll give you the answer check.
....WORKING CODE:
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: '/Schedule/getSubdivisions', ... });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the $.ajax call so that it does not use a relative path... Everything works now.

Answer (score -1):

Using Html.Raw to solve you problem,
The reponse string was encoded, add 
  `@Html.Raw(data)` in your js script

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not understand what you are saying. I solved the problem by changing the URL so it did not use a relative path. I can't use @Html.Raw because my JavaScript is not in a view; my JavaScript is in a separate file.

Comment: I'm sorry, tommorow, i have same problem with the response string, it was enscript and got error. You do good job